# Error using getView() with a Listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, getview

I'm am a newbie with Android development and using the following example to do something similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11626706/5724649

But am getting the following error: `"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference"`when I try to set one of the radio button.  Also `mSource` (which is an ArrayList) is `null` within `getView()`, so I see why I could get this error, but not sure as to how I should pass the `arraylist` to `getView()`.  Please help.

Comment: We need to see the exact code you are using, please add it to this question so we can easily see it without having to follow links. Please include any modifications you have made to that sample and the line number at which the error occurs. The line number should be shown in the error output. Thanks

Comment: Did you initialize and populate the arraylist mSource = new Arraylist()

Comment: code sample please. Your app has logic we cant comprehend without sample code

Answer (score 0):

The error is about you calling a method on an object which currently "null".

This will also throw the same error:

```
    String a = null;
    a.length(); // <<< This will cause an error, because a is null.
```

You should make sure the following line:

```
    mSource = new ArrayList<RowObject>();
```

is running before any of these lines:

```
    mSource.get(position).setFirstChecked(true);

    mSource.get(position).setFirstChecked(false);

    if (mSource.get(position).isFirstChecked()) {
```